# Задал вопрос через 2 года после последнего посещения

Tags: дефект

[Вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/206783/178988) был задан через 2 года после последнего посещения сайта [его автором](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2122/oleg-ismaylov).

[The question](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/206783/178988) was asked 2 years latter then [its author](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2122/oleg-ismaylov) was last seen.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Кстати, плюсище за нарисованные круги и стрелку!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это норма! Если участник не заходил после миграции, то датой его последнего посещения считается дата регистрации на сайте.

Наверняка разработчики просто не стали переносить эту информацию, т.к. она не особо критична, либо Хэшкод её изначально не хранил.

Comment: Во избежании подобных вопросов, было бы неплохо пройтись разово по пользователям и проставить дату последнего посещения равной хотя бы дате последнего сообщения/комментария.

Comment: @alexolut Оформите как ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov думаете, в комментариях этому тексту не место?

Comment: @alexolut а зачем? Текущая ситуация создает проблемы?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Да ну это же безобразие, давайте это исправим. Тем более что это исправляется совсем несложным SQL-запросом. Проблема в неверной информации.

Comment: Ситуация порождает вопросы, которых можно было бы избежать.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov править это вряд ли кто-то будет в силу незначительности проблемы. Но поправить, безусловно, было бы хорошо.

Comment: @alexolut Очень даже место комментарию, просто мне ответ, что "это норма" и надо всё оставить как есть не нравится.

Answer (score 4):

Как предложил [@alexolut](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/alexolut):
Во избежании подобных вопросов, было бы неплохо пройтись разово по пользователям и проставить дату последнего посещения равной хотя бы дате последнего сообщения/комментария.