# Ошибки с последним посещением

Tags: дефект, поддержка

Очень часто вижу эту ошибку. Сегодня не выдержал и решил запостить.

Фото вырезаны в одно и то же время.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Что с этим делать? Или я как-то не понимаю?

Comment: Бывает и веселее: [Задал вопрос через 2 года после последнего посещения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4654/Задал-вопрос-через-2-года-после-последнего-посещения)